# Next.js 14 - Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

This is my Main page

```
"use server";
import Container from "../components/Container";
import CollectionCard from "../components/products/CollectionCard";
import getProducts, { IProductParams } from "@/actions/getProducts";
import NullData from "../components/NullData";
import Heading from "../components/Headings";
import { categories } from "@/utils/categories";

export default async function Collections() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="mt-10">
        {" "}
        <Heading title="Collections" center />
      </div>

      <div
        className="mt-10 grid 
        grid-cols-1
        sm:grid-cols-1 
        lg:grid-cols-4
        xl:grid-col-4
        2xl:grid-col-4 
        gap-8"
      >
        {categories.map((category: any) => {
          return <CollectionCard key={category.id} data={category} />;
        })}{" "}
        *
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

**This is my client component**

```
"use client";

import { formatPrice } from "@/utils/formatprice";
import { truncatetext } from "@/utils/truncateText";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Rating } from "@mui/material";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

interface ProductCardProps {
  data: any;
}

const ProductCard: React.FC<ProductCardProps> = ({data}) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  //const productrating =
  //data.reviews.reduce((acc: number, item: any) => item.rating + acc, 0) /
  //   data.reviews.length;

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => router.push(`/product/${data.id}`)}
      className="
      col-span-1
      cursor-pointer
      border-[1.2px]
      border-slate-200
      bg-slate-50
      rounded-sm
      p-2
      trasition
      hover:scale-105
      text-center
      text-sm
      "
    >
      <div
        className="
        flex
        flex-col
        items-center
        w-full
        gap-1"
      >
        <div
          className="
          aspect-square 
          overflow-hidden
          relative
          w-full"
        >
          <Image
            fill
            src={data.images[0].image}
            alt={data.name}
            className="w-full h-full object-contain"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4">{truncatetext(data.name)}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

**I got this error here**

*Error: Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
{id: 1, label: ..., icon: function, images: ...}*

**please be kind enough to fix this error **
(this error says to add "use server" to the main component but it is still not working)